# Filter by rank of one index level in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a Dataframe with customer `id`, `date` and `price` and I want to aggregate all prices except for the purchase of each `id` on the first date.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,2,4],[1,3,1],[2,2,1],[2,3,3]], columns=["id", "date", "price"])
s=df.groupby(["id","date"]).price.sum()
# id  date
# 1   1       2
#     2       5
#     3       1
# 2   2       1
#     3       3
```

I'd like to sum all prices except for the ones on the smallest dates for each id (date 1 for id 1; and date 2 for id 2). The result would be 5+1+3=9.

So, I'd have to rank on part of the index with-in groups and combine this result with the previous aggregation?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the level as follows:

```
s = s.sortlevel([0,1])
```

We can just first sum by group (ignoring first unit), and then sum over the result

```
In[153]: s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: sum(x.iloc[1:]))
Out[153]: 
id
1     6
2     3
dtype: int64
In[154]: s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: sum(x.iloc[1:])).sum()
Out[154]: 9
```

If you want more advanced stuff which does not follow from logic that the `iloc[]` operator can work with, you should have a separate function instead of the `lambda`

```
import numpy as np
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return True
    for i in np.arange(2, n-1):
        if (n%i) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def select_and_sum(group):
    n = len(group)
    r = range(n)
    primes = [j for j in r if is_prime(j) == True]
    return group.iloc[primes].sum()

s.groupby(level=0).apply(select_and_sum)
```

Comment: Is there an intermediate step possible to ensure they are really ordered? (or maybe to make more complex selections on the ranks?)

Comment: Added sorting snippet. As for complex selections, what do you mean? Ignoring the first two rows per group would be `iloc[2:]`, c.p.

Comment: Well, maybe selecting prime number ranks :) Something more universal if I had to select by weekday or so.

Comment: Thanks. Strictly speaking it doesn't do rank, but I think I can find that :)